# Wordpress pagination going on Page not Found

Tags: wordpress, pagination, http-status-code-404

i m applying pagination on archive.php, but the pagination links not working and going on 404.php. my code is below, i did also changed permalink setting, also did set to default but failed. it display pagination but links are broken.
please guide me if anyone can. thanks alot

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('showposts=1&cat=44'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;
if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
    wp_pagenavi();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

which version of WP do you use? 
For  WordPress 3.x or higher

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

And you must go to the settings>permalinks and just hit save without changing anything, but WP is triggering something.

Hope it helps

Comment: Tried this, which was a variation (using page instead of paged) and it doesn't stop the pagination from redirecting to 404 page.. see post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434889/wordpress-blog-pagination-returning-404-page-with-post-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

Pagination uses posts_per_page set in the global options. If this is less than the available posts then there will be a 404. Try amending the posts_per_page to a lower number.

As per this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/80423/38077

You can see the keys and values of all available options by manually entering the admin url:

/wp-admin/options.php

Total number of posts:

```
global $wp_query;
$total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
```