# Wordpress blog pagination returning 404 page with $post not defined

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pagination, http-status-code-404

I've setup a blog on an older site and have tried everything to get the pagination to work.

Here is the code from the category-blog.php file:

```
    <section>
    <div id="content">
        <h1 class="blog-heading">In The News</h1>
            <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            get_posts(array(
                'post_type'      => 'post', // You can add a custom post type if you like
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' => 4
            ));
            ?>
        <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>

            <div id="blog-grid">

                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>         
                <div class="blog-post" id="blog-post-<?php get_the_ID(); ?>">                   
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'blog-index' ); ?></a>
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <div class="readmore-link">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                    </div><!-- end div.readmore-link -->                        
                </div><!-- end div.blog-post -->
                <?php endwhile; ?>                  
            </div><!-- end div#blog-grid -->

            <div class="pagination">
                <?php my_pagination(); ?>
            </div><!-- /.navigation -->

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- end content -->
</section>
```

and the functions.php file

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'my_pagination' ) ) :
    function my_pagination() {
        global $wp_query;

        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        $paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
            //'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'prev_next' => False
        ) );
        if ( $paginate_links ) {
            echo $paginate_links;
        }

    }
endif;
```

When I access the blog page at /blog I can see the listing of posts.. as expected. The pagination renders below the posts (again, as expected) but when you navigate to, say, page 2.. you go to /blog/page/2/ and get a 404 error stating $post is not defined!

I've tried to overcome this with every post I could find online, from declaring posts_per_page and pre_get_posts in the functions.php like:

```
define('PER_PAGE_DEFAULT', 4);
function my_post_count_queries( $query ) {
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
       $query->set('posts_per_page', 4);
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_count_queries' );

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_blog_query' );
function modify_blog_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 4 );
    }
}


function change_posts_per_page(){ return 1; }
if( preg_match("|\/".get_option('tag_base')."\/.+\/page\/[0-9]+$|i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ){
    add_filter( 'pre_option_posts_per_page' , 'change_posts_per_page');
}
```

and even going to far as modify the .htaccess rewrite rules to ignore the /blog pages.. I even installed a couple plugins, which rendered the pagination as my function does.. and still resulted in a 404.

I've also replaced the entire pagination function with standard Prev/Next, with the same results:

```
                    <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
```

Lastly, since this is an existing, live site.. I cannot disable any existing plugins to see if one or more are causing a conflict or error.

Any help and feedback on the best/a better way to do this, is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED**

I replaced the get_posts query with a custom query.. based on Nathan's recommendation below (thanks for that!).. still, same 404 on pagination links.

Here is the custom query I used:

```
        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query_args = array( 
                            'post_type'=> 'post',
                            'posts_per_page' => 4,
                            'paged'=> $paged
                        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $wp_query_args );
        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div id="blog-grid">
        <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="blog-post" id="blog-post-<?php get_the_ID(); ?>">                   
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'blog-index' ); ?></a>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <div class="readmore-link">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
            </div><!-- end div.readmore-link -->                        
        </div><!-- end div.blog-post -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div><!-- end div#blog-grid -->    
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="pagination">
            <?php my_pagination(); ?>
        </div><!-- /.navigation -->

        <?php 
          $wp_query = null; 
          $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
        ?>
```

**SECOND UPDATE**

This page is live, so I'm providing a link for those willing to help, to test with:

[Blog Index](http://www.deltacomputergroup.com/blog/)

[Blog Page 2, Error page](http://www.deltacomputergroup.com/blog/page/2/)

Comment: As a side note, I'm using a template file named 'category-blog.php' and the single.php to render the blog index and single posts, respectively.. I also reverted to using the archive.php file.. but that didn't fix the pagination.

Comment: `get_posts` will return an array. Because you don't use it immediately or assign it to a variable the result is thrown away. I suspect you were looking for `WP_Query` instead. Please be sure to lookup `WP_Query` before using - it's not a like-for-like replacement. `pre_get_posts` is the right approach.

Comment: I just replaced the get_posts call with a custom query.. and reset that query so as not to effect the main query... still, same issue..  UPDATED original post with code I tested with

Comment: Also, turned on Debug and Display Errors.. no errors, aside from the '$post not found' when navigating to another page from pagination.

Comment: So, further research shows that it's NOT the category-blog.php file that is creating the error.. when you click on a pagination link you see an error, but that is because WP is redirecting to the lefit 404.php page.. so, somewhere, somehow, WP is seeing the pagination links as invalid, and redirecting it incorrectly. Man.. frustrating. I've reset and re-saved the Permalinks settings (set to /%category%/%postname%/) without effect. - I even tried renaming the 'blog' category to 'bogs' in case that was conflicting with the permalinks.. nope.

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of research, fiddling and coding.. I realized that the pagination function was not adding the category base to the link - eg. /category/blog/ and only returning /bog/ ... oddly enough, the /blog page worked... but, when paging, it didn't.

So, I created a new template and renamed the category. I installed WP_PageNavi and used that for pagination. That resolved the issue.. so, this pagination function that's floating around, that a lot of people seem to be using, is not working properly.

Namely, this one:

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'my_pagination' ) ) :
    function my_pagination() {
        global $wp_query;

        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
         if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
             $format = 'category/page/%#%';
         } else {
             $format = 'category/?paged=%#%';
         }

        $paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            //'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big) ),
            'format' => $format,
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'prev_next' => False
        ) );
        if ( $paginate_links ) {
            echo $paginate_links;
        }

    }
endif;
```

It will not prepend the category base path.. which causes the pagination to fail the redirect.